# How can I set up DogeCoin wallet on Ubuntu?

Tags: wallet, linux, ubuntu, dogecoin

I just newly introduced with Dogecoins, how can I set up wallet to store Dogecoins on my Ubuntu machine? I have tried lots of references but I cant get simple way. May I know how can mine Dogecoins from Ubuntu Machine?

Comment: What have you tried? What are you having trouble with? This question does not currently contain enough detail to answer.

Comment: @GregHewgill I want to install Wallet for Dogecoin on my ubuntu machine, how can I do that?

Comment: Please add more details: what have you tried? How have those attempts failed? Did you read a number of sites and were their instructions unclear? Plus be aware mining and having a wallet are different things.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use a [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~cwayne18/+archive/doge). Once you add the PPA to your apt sources, you can install it using `apt-get` just like any other apt package.

Just run the following and you're good to go!

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cwayne18/doge
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install dogecoin-qt
```

Please note: When you use a PPA, you have to trust that the person maintaining the PPA doesn't do anything malicious. For the highest security, compile the source yourself.